# C++ Error: Why do I have to create pointer object of class Stack?

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, stack, singly-linked-list

I started programming in Cpp few days back so I am still getting familiar with concept of pointer. I know programming style and logic is crude.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class node
{
public:
    int data;
    node *next;
    node() 
    {
        data = 0;
        next = nullptr;
    }
};


class Stack
{
private:
    node *top;
    node *first;
public:
    Stack();
    void push();
    void display();
};

Stack::Stack() 
{
    top = new node();
}

void Stack::push()
{
    int data;
    cout<<"Enter data: ";
    cin>>data;
    node *n = new node();
    n->data = data;
    if(top->next == nullptr)
    {
        top->next = n;
    }
    else
    {
        node *temp = new node();
        temp = top;
        while(temp->next != nullptr) 
        {
            cout<<"while here!"<<endl;
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        temp->next = n;
    } 
}

void Stack::display() 
{
    node *temp;
    temp = top;
    while(!(temp->next == nullptr))
    {
        cout<<temp->next->data<<" ";
        temp = temp->next; 
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n, ch;
    bool isTrue = true;
    Stack *s = new Stack();
    //Stack s();
    cout<<"1.Push\n2.Display\n3.Exit"<<endl;
    while (isTrue)
    {
        cout<<"Enter Your Choice: ";
        cin>>ch;
        switch (ch)
        {
        case 1:
            //s.push();  //Editor was pointing here  
            s->push();
            break;

        case 2:
               //s.display();  //Editor was pointing here
            s->display();
            break;

        case 3:
            isTrue = false;
            break;

        default:
            cout<<"Wrong Choice!"<<endl;
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

when i created `object s` of `class Stack` in stack memory I was unable to call any function. `s.display` and `s.push` is where editor is pointing and saying *Expression must have a class type*. I searched about it a lot and couldn't find a solution. So, I created `object s` of `class Stack` in heap memory (I don't know why maybe I had a gut feeling that it might work) and it actually worked but I still unable to understand why.
May you explain why?

Comment: `Stack s();` is a declaration of a function taking no parameters and returning `Stack`. If you meant to declare a variable, that would be `Stack s;`

Comment: Google for vexing parse. [https://www.fluentcpp.com/2018/01/30/most-vexing-parse/](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2018/01/30/most-vexing-parse/)